# VBA type mismatch error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, vba, dynamics-gp

I have no clue what this is. Apparently it has to be some syntax error of some sort but I can not figure out what it is for the life of me! All I am doing is save data into a table in SQL Server 2008 and I am using vba in microsoft dynamics great plains 2010. The specific line it is throwing an error is

```
 rs("FREIGHT_RATE") = frmItemProfile.txtFreightRate
```

but it seems to change lines whenever I make an adjustment, so there is probably something wrong in this method somewhere. The error message only says "type mismatch"  Any Help would be amazing.

```vb
Public Sub SaveRecord(strItemNumber As String)
Dim qry As String
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'query table name
    qry = "SELECT * FROM dbo.PCI_ITEM_PROFILE where ITEMNMBR = '" & strItemNumber & "'"

'open recordset
    rs.Open qry, strDSNPCI, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic

        If rs.EOF <> True Then
            'Time to Update Record
                rs("RCD_KEY") = frmItemProfile.txtRCDKey
                If frmItemProfile.txtCopyRightDate = "" Then
                    rs("COPYRIGHT_DATE") = #1/1/1900#
                Else
                    rs("COPYRIGHT_DATE") = frmItemProfile.txtCopyRightDate
                End If
                rs("FIRST_CATALOG") = frmItemProfile.txtFirstCatalog
                rs("CATEGORY") = frmItemProfile.txtCategory
                rs("SERIES_CD") = frmItemProfile.txtSeriesCD
                rs("PARENT_CD") = frmItemProfile.txtParentCD
                rs("TYPE") = frmItemProfile.txtType
                rs("COMMODITY_CD") = frmItemProfile.txtCommodityCD
                rs("BARCODE_1") = frmItemProfile.txtBarCodeOne
                rs("BARCODE_2") = frmItemProfile.txtBarCodeTwo
                rs("BARCODE_3") = frmItemProfile.txtBarCodeThree
                rs("BARCODE_4") = frmItemProfile.txtBarCodeFour
                rs("CLASS_GROUP") = frmItemProfile.cmbClassGroup
                rs("FREIGHT_RATE") = frmItemProfile.txtFreightRate
                rs("ITEM_LENGTH") = frmItemProfile.txtItemLength
                rs("ITEM_WIDTH") = frmItemProfile.txtItemWidth
                rs("ITEM_HEIGHT") = frmItemProfile.txtItemHeight
                rs("USER2ENT") = frmItemProfile.txtUserEnt
                rs("CREATE_DATE") = frmItemProfile.txtCreateDate
                rs("MODIFDT") = frmItemProfile.txtModifyDate
                rs("IN_KIT") = frmItemProfile.txtInKit
                rs("IN_BOM") = frmItemProfile.txtInBom
                rs("REP_COMM_PCT") = frmItemProfile.txtRepPct
                rs("REP_COMM_EXCEPT") = frmItemProfile.txtRepCommExcept
                rs("ROYALTY_ITEM") = frmItemProfile.txtRoyaltyItem
                rs("PPC_PAGES") = frmItemProfile.txtPPCPages
                rs("PPC_PAPER") = frmItemProfile.txtPPCPaper
                rs("PPC_TONERCURVE") = frmItemProfile.txtPPCTonerCurve
                rs("PPC_COIL") = frmItemProfile.txtPPCCoil
                rs("PPC_IMPRESSIONS") = frmItemProfile.txtPPCImpressions
                rs("DROP_SHIP_ITEM") = frmItemProfile.txtDropShipItem
                rs("OP_CD") = frmItemProfile.txtOPCD
                If frmItemProfile.txtOPDate = "" Then
                    rs("OP_DATE") = #1/1/1900#
                Else
                    rs("OP_DATE") = frmItemProfile.txtOPDate
                End If
                rs("NOTES") = frmItemProfile.txtNotes
                rs.Update
        End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Comment: This message indicates that the value of frmItemProfile.txtFreightRate is not allowable for the MS-SQL FREIGHT_RATE type, which is ??? float ???.  Usually debugging the code and looking at the value is the best way to see what is going on.

Comment: yes it is a float. Is there an issue with float?

Comment: Its just a task of going through all the types of the record sets and the types which your trying to pass to them. Try doing one at a time and testing each one to see exactly which ones are falling over

Comment: It is typically the correct type for a freight column, but if the value you are trying to set it to is non-numeric and error will ensue. You can try testing for IsNumeric( frmItemProfile.txtFreightRate) and assigning 0 (or Null if you wish) and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: ahh Ron, thats it. Sheeesh something so stupid. Create an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible repro:

```
Dim rs
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

With rs
  .Fields.Append "FREIGHT_RATE", adDouble, , 32  ' adFldIsNullable
  .Open
  .AddNew
  rs("FREIGHT_RATE") = "fifty-five"

End With
```

The error I get:

> Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.